# Can i reuse apps from my old phone sd card in new phone?

Tags: storage, sd-card

I was using Lumia 520 for 2 years. I had all apps installed on my phone memory. After 8.1 update I moved all apps to sd card.
Now I have bought Lumia 730, and inserted the same sd card in it. Now under storage sense when I select store new apps on sd card, it says sd card contains app from another phone, to install apps on sd card you have to delete apps from another phone first.

Now I don't want to delete those apps, i have important things stored under few apps which I dont want to loose.

What can I do to not loose that data? Official windows doc also says I have to delete those apps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks I have no way but to delete all apps. Microsoft should rethink on this design decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you will have to reinstall all apps as they the files on the SD card are bound to your old phones ID. 
You can insert the SD Jonny your old phone, make a backup there and restore it on your new device - this way you don't have to download all apps manually.

Comment: My 520 got corrupted with error, Unable to find the bootable Press any key to shutdown. So I had to bought new one hence repairing old one would cost some good amount of money which will replace motherboard. Looks no way to but to erase existing apps.

Comment: I guess so, sorry. You can find a list of your owned apps in the store, though